Plotly indicator plot for specific values
Code bellow gives me plot for value 20 from 30.
How can I change max of this plot (in my example 30)?
library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly(
  domain = list(x = c(0, 1), y = c(0, 1)),
  
 value = 20,
  title = list(text = "Speed"),
  type = "indicator",
  mode = "gauge+number"
 )
fig <- fig %>%
  layout(margin = list(l=2,r=3))

fig


You can set the range of the gauge like so:
library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly(
  domain = list(x = c(0, 1), y = c(0, 1)),
  value = 20,
  title = list(text = "Speed"),
  type = "indicator",
  mode = "gauge+number",
  gauge = list(
    axis = list(
      range = c(0, 40)
    )
  )
)

fig <- fig %>%
  layout(margin = list(l = 50, r = 50))

fig


